# How to convert a Dataset[Seq[T]] to Dataset[T] in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

How do I convert a `Dataset[Seq[T]]` to `Dataset[T]`?

For example, `Dataset[Seq[Car]]` to `Dataset[Car]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do flatMap:

```
val df = Seq(Seq(1, 2, 3), Seq(4, 5, 6, 7)).toDF("s").as[Seq[Int]];
df.flatMap(x => x.toList)
```

You can also try explode function:

```
df.select(explode('s)).select("col.*").as[Car]
```

Full example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
case class Car(i : Int);
val df = Seq(List(Car(1), Car(2), Car(3))).toDF("s").as[List[Car]];
val df1 = df.flatMap(x  => x.toList)
val df2 = df.select(explode('s)).select("col.*").as[Car]
```